# What is gensim's simple_preprocess alternative in Scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, gensim

Using Gensim to perform LDA, I was able to do initial text preprocessing and cleanup using:

```
gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence),deacc=True)
```

It was very efficient and almost does all required forms of text cleanup in one command. Now, I am trying to learn LDA using Scikit learn and I was wondering if there is a similar way to achieve the same preprocessing using Sci-kit learn, instead of having to load both libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `scikit-learn` provides a similar utility function, but the whole logic of what Gensim's `simple_preprocess()` is doing is only about 20 lines of source code, spread across 5 functions:

1. [`simple_preprocess()`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/0bd1d0651f7a52e1b6bb38529161e395986a803e/gensim/utils.py#L288), which relies on...
2. [`tokenize()`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/0bd1d0651f7a52e1b6bb38529161e395986a803e/gensim/utils.py#L227), which relies on...
3. [`to_unicode()`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/0bd1d0651f7a52e1b6bb38529161e395986a803e/gensim/utils.py#L345), [`deaccent()`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/0bd1d0651f7a52e1b6bb38529161e395986a803e/gensim/utils.py#L174), & [`simple_tokenize()`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/0bd1d0651f7a52e1b6bb38529161e395986a803e/gensim/utils.py#L270)

So if you wanted the same behavior, without installing Gensim, you have the option to just copy & paste (or otherwise lightly adapt) that source code.